# mysql query to get all the unit that a student not enrolled in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `chosenunit` and `units`. In `chosenunit` table there are 2 columns `student_id` and `unit_id` . Units table has `unit_id` and `unit_name` columns with all the units in the system. Lets say there are 2 students with ids of 1000 and 1001. They are enrolled in several units. chosenunit table will look like this:

```
(1000,2000),
(1000,2001),
(1000,2006),
(1001,2000),
(1001,2004),
```

I need to get all the units that a student is not enrolled in. If 1000 logs in to the system,it need to show all the unit_names of all the subjects except 2000,2001,2006.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many possible solutions on this problem.

**first** is by using `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    units a
        LEFT JOIN choseunits b
            ON a.unit_ID = b.unit_ID AND
                b.student_ID = 1000
WHERE   b.unit_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04886/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

**Second** is by using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    unit a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    choseunit b
            WHERE   a.unit_ID = b.unit_ID AND
                    b.student_ID = 1000
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04886/3)